# Carplay connect/disconnect events?

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

Is there a way to detect in an app if the phone was connected/disconnected to/from the car using Carplay?
Can't seem to find any documentation regarding it.
I'm thinking of some system event like that I could monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed these steps?

1. Add corresponding record to your project's Entitlements file: `com.apple.developer.carplay-maps` type of `Boolean` with value `YES`
2. [Request from Apple corresponding permission](https://developer.apple.com/contact/carplay/)
3. Make your AppDelegate confirm to `CPApplicationDelegate` protocol
4. Implement the next methods:

   ```
   /**
    The CarPlay screen has connected and is ready to present content.

    Your app should create its view controller and assign it to the @c rootViewController property
    of this window.

    @note It is the responsibility of the delegate to maintain a reference to the interface controller beyond the scope of this method.
    */
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didConnectCarInterfaceController:(CPInterfaceController *)interfaceController toWindow:(CPWindow *)window;
    /**
    The CarPlay screen has disconnected.
     */
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didDisconnectCarInterfaceController:(CPInterfaceController *)interfaceController fromWindow:(CPWindow *)window;
   ```

Please, check this [Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpapplicationdelegate) and [this WWDC 2018 Carplay Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/213/)

Comment: Note that this only applies to CarPlay navigation apps. Audio apps should not need to take care about that connection state.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer Im building out an Audio app, is there an equivalent call for Audio apps that you are aware of? Im trying to find a good place to load my data/

Comment: @MiMo Nothing prevents you from doing it unconditionally in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, if there is no CarPlay, it will just not be used.

Then again, if you absolutely insist, a worthwhile approach may be listening for Audio Output Route changes – perhaps this will be triggered on connection/disconnection of CarPlay.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer loading my data includes a call to the api, parsing, I'd rather not do it on every applicationDidFinishLaunch since the app without CarPlay never needs that data at applicationDidFinishLaunch.

Comment: @Mimo: I see, and I agree. Please open a feature wish against the Apple bug tracker, CarPlay Audio apps should deserve proper (dis)connection callbacks same as Map apps.

Comment: It does appear that you do need com.apple.developer.carplay-maps in the entitlement file in order for the CPApplicationDelegate methods to be called, but this is indeed intended for maps apps only. It is indeed unfortunate there aren't similar callbacks for Audio apps.